# Use Gram-Schmidt to find a normal to an affine hull

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Problem 9.11.5: Find a normal for each of the following planes in $R^3$ .

1. $Span \{[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]\}$
2. $Span \{[2, 1, −3], [−2, 1, 1]\}$
3. affine hull of $[3, 1, 4], [5, 2, 6]$, and $[2, 3, 5].$

The book I am using does not provide solutions. Now I know how to find the orthogonal complement of a plane in $R^3$ using Gram-Schmidt, and I figure the orthogonal complement to a plane is the 'normal' to it. However, I am not sure how I would find the 'normal' to an Affine Space using Gram-Schmidt. Is there a way to do this? If not how should I go about it?

Comment: It's called Gram--Schmidt; in reference to  two separate persons. You can [edit] the post.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1:**

Every plane is of the form $\vec{x}+\text{span}(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$.  $\vec{n}$ is defined to be perpendicular to that plane iff it is perpendicular to $\text{span}(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$.  Can you determine a $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ for which the plane in part (c) is of this form?

**Solution #2:**

What do you know about the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)?